# This keyword in typescript doesn't refer to class

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have problem with 'this' keyword in typescript. As you can see below, I want to call method1 from some 'inside' function, for example FileReader.onloadend method. Hovewer, 'this' references to FileReader, not to class foo. How can I change my code to make this work?

```
export class foo {

   constructor() {
       this.method2();
   }

   public method1() {
      console.log('method1 called');         // this never happens
   }

   public method2() {
      let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          console.log(this)                  //it prints FileReader object
          this.method1();                    //I want this to be refered to class foo
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new function literal syntax with far arrows:

```
public method2() {
  let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = (e) => {
      console.log(this) //it no longer prints FileReader object
      this.method1();   //method1 called
  }
}
```

Using far arrows, `this` now always refers to the class, instead of the function scope. You can check out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions) for more information on Lexical `this` and the short form function syntax.

The documentation is for ES6, but it applies equally to Typescript, since it's a strict superset.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    console.log(this)                  //it prints FileReader object
    this.method1();                    //I want this to be refered to class foo
}
```

to this:

```
reader.onloadend = (e) => {
    console.log(this)                  //it prints FileReader object
    this.method1();                    //I want this to be refered to class foo
}
```

You can read more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).